# SQL query where one attribute is same while other is unequal

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have something like the following database table:

| id_x | type | timestamp1 | timestamp2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 08.01.2022 |  |
| 1 | B | 31.02.2021 | 01.01.2022 |
| 2 | B | 28.01.2017 | 25.07.2021 |
| 2 | A | 25.07.2021 |  |

I am looking for a query that can return all `id_x` where there exists multiple entries for `id_x` where one is of type **A** and one is of type **B** AND `timestamp1` of the row of type **A** is not the same as `timestamp2` of the row with type **B**.

So in the example above it should return only `id_x=1` but not `id_x=2`, because the `timestamp1` in the `id_x=2` row with type **A** is the same as the `timestamp2` of the row of `id_x=2` with type **B**.

Comment: For one id_x: are there always exactly two entries A and B? Or can there be multiple A, multiple B, no A, no B, other types (C, D, ...)? What to do in any of these cases?

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT id_x
FROM test
GROUP BY id_x
             -- where one is of type A and one is of type B
HAVING GROUP_CONCAT(type ORDER BY type) = 'A,B'
             -- timestamp1 of the row of type A is not the same as timestamp2 of the row with type B
   AND NOT MAX(CASE WHEN type='A' THEN timestamp1 END) <=> MAX(CASE WHEN type='B' THEN timestamp2 END)
```

If `timestamp1` is defined as NOT NULL then

```sql
   AND MAX(CASE WHEN type='A' THEN timestamp1 END) <> MAX(CASE WHEN type='B' THEN timestamp2 END)
```